# Survey123 get data off phone in outbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I created a field survey with a ''field'' which was not long enough. This has resulted
in me not being able to publish the data. I can however send it to my outbox.

I created a new survey and fixed the issue, However I am wanting to take the data from the outbox off my phone.

Is there a way I can do this? With a cable perhaps? Or can I change the field in AGOL to be longer?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the similar problem and after reading discussions in the https://community.esri.com/, I found [this very useful troubleshooting page](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/get-answers/troubleshootgetanswers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_A972F8032F3541B1B1809D81B2D4BED9). My approach was as follows:

- Locate and copy the `.sqlite` database in the mobile device
- Generate a local copy of the sqlite table in a FGDB
- Create an empty feature class with the required schema (i.e., from the source hosted feature layer of the Survey123)
- From `data` column of the relevant `Surveys` that you want to extract, read json and populate empty feature class with attributes including `location/Shape`
- `Append` this feature class to the source feature layer of the Survey123

If you have attachments, you will need an extra step

- Copy content of the .\arcgis\My Survey Attachments folder and rematch the names to reattach.

Also, [this GIS-SE post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292783/importing-survey123-sqlite-database-from-device/293543#293543) might be of help but you may need to tweak its parameters to match JSON attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved using ArcGIS Online as follows:

- View the survey's hosted feature layer in ArcGIS Online, and switch to its data (table)view
- Create a new (temporary) field
- Calculate the values for the new temporary field to be the same as the values of the original field
- Delete the original field (after confirming that the new temporary field holds all the correct values of the original field)
- Create another new (permanent) field with the same name as the original field, but with the required longer length
- Calculate the values of the new permanent field to be the same as the values of the temporary field

This should resolve the problem. Depending on how your survey is configured, you may also have to explicitly update the field length in the survey configuration to match.  Finally, re-publish the survey.

Comment: I think that even though this is partially solves the problem (OP asks transferring data from old survey records stuck in the mobile device, e.g., Outbox, to new survey), it is a good approach to solve problem in the source survey, then the records can be transferred to anywhere basically. Instead of ArcGIS Online, I rather prefer to change schema in ArcGIS Survey123 Connect and set a Calculate rule to populate the new (maybe hidden) large field in XLSForm.